# Script breaks when changing values

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

So this wasn't an easy post to title but what I am trying to accomplish is have a grid of squares that randomly change colors with adjustable values for height, width, spacing, and timing for the grid.

```
var c=document.getElementById("myCanvas");
        var ctx=c.getContext("2d");
        ctx.canvas.width  = window.innerWidth;
        ctx.canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
        var width = window.innerWidth;
        var height = window.innerHeight;

        function toggleSettings(){
            var displayValue = document.getElementById("settingsMenu").style.display;
            if (displayValue == "block"){
                document.getElementById("settingsMenu").style.display = "none";
            } else {
                document.getElementById("settingsMenu").style.display = "block";
            }
        }

        var blockWidth =32;
        var blockHeight = 32;
        var blockSpacingX = 64;
        var blockSpacingY = 64;
        var refreshTime = 200;

        function updateVariables(){
            ctx.fillStyle="#000000";
            ctx.fillRect(0, 0, width, height);
            blockWidth = document.getElementById("blockWidth").value;
            blockHeight = document.getElementById("blockHeight").value;
            blockSpacingX = document.getElementById("blockSpacingX").value;
            blockSpacingY = document.getElementById("blockSpacingY").value;
            refreshTime = document.getElementById("refreshTime").value;
            refreshInterval();
        }

        var startInterval = setInterval(mainLoop, refreshTime);

        function refreshInterval() {
            clearInterval(startInterval);
            startInterval = setInterval(mainLoop, refreshTime);
        }

        function mainLoop(){
            for (y=0; y< height; y=y+blockSpacingY) {
                for (x=0; x < width; x=x+blockSpacingX) {
                ctx.fillStyle='#'+Math.floor(Math.random()*16777215).toString(16);
                ctx.fillRect(x, y, blockWidth, blockHeight);
                }
            }
        }
```

Everything works fine except for when I add these two lines into updateVariables():

```
blockSpacingX = document.getElementById("blockSpacingX").value;
blockSpacingY = document.getElementById("blockSpacingY").value;
```

Changing their variables manually and then reloading the page works fine but for some reason it breaks ALL of the inputs and only puts 4 squares at the top left of the canvas.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/L8909prp/

Comment: I started to pin-point the problem when I put the x- and y-coordinates in the console-log. I got: x:064 y:064 so a 0 is added to the mix. That might be what is causing the problem. Solved it by putting `parseInt()` around all your variables that you're getting from DOMs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An all to common trap for beginners. You are getting the wrong type when you use

```
blockWidth = document.getElementById("blockWidth").value;
```

This returns a string not a number, in the for loop the addition concatonates strings, not adds values.

you have...

```
for (y = 0; y < height; y = y + blockSpacingY) {
```

which will result in

```
blockSpacingY = "33"
y = 0;
y = y + blockSpacingY;
// now y === "033" 
// next itteration y === "03333"
```

To solve, ensure the value you get from the inputs is of type Number

```
blockSpacingY = document.getElementById("blockSpacingY").value;
```

Should be.

```
blockSpacingY = parseInt(document.getElementById("blockSpacingY").value,10);
// or I prefer
blockSpacingY = Number(document.getElementById("blockSpacingY").value);
```

Do that for all inputs and that will fix your problem.

While I am here I will show you some simple ways to improve your code.

```
    var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
    var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
    ctx.canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
    ctx.canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
    var width = window.innerWidth;
    var height = window.innerHeight;
    var blockWidth = 32;
    var blockHeight = 32;
    var blockSpacingX = 64;
    var blockSpacingY = 64;
    var refreshTime = 200;
    var backGroundChange = false; // flag to tell background to change

    // using getElementById is very slow. Do it once at the beginning of 
    // your code and store the DOM elements in a variable. That means your code does not 
    // have to walk the entier DOM tree each time you need to acccess the elements
    var settingsMenuEl = document.getElementById("settingsMenu"); 
    var blockWidthEl = document.getElementById("blockWidth");
    var blockHeightEl = document.getElementById("blockHeight");
    var blockSpacingXEl = document.getElementById("blockSpacingX");
    var blockSpacingYEl = document.getElementById("blockSpacingY");
    var refreshTimeEl = document.getElementById("refreshTime");

    // dont use inline code in you HTML set up the events here
    // remove the oninput="updateVariables();" from the HTML
    blockWidthEl.addEventListener("input",updateVariables);
    blockHeightEl.addEventListener("input",updateVariables);
    blockSpacingXEl.addEventListener("input",updateVariables);
    blockSpacingYEl.addEventListener("input",updateVariables);
    refreshTimeEl.addEventListener("input",updateVariables);


    function toggleSettings() {
        var displayValue = settingsMenuEl.style.display; // use the previouse set element ref
        if (displayValue == "block") {
            settingsMenuEl.style.display = "none";
        } else {
            settingsMenuEl.style.display = "block";
        }
    }


    function updateVariables() {
        blockWidth = Number(blockWidthEl.value);
        blockHeight = Number(blockHeightEl.value);
        blockSpacingX = Number(blockSpacingXEl.value);
        blockSpacingY = Number(blockSpacingYEl.value);
        refreshTime = Number(refreshTimeEl.value);
        backGroundChange = true;  // try to keep all rendering as close as possible
        // refreshInterval(); no need for this as it is happening anyways
    }

    // all the messing about with intervals is overkill and not needed.
    // remove it all
    //var startInterval = setInterval(mainLoop, refreshTime);
    //function refreshInterval() {
    //    clearInterval(startInterval);
    //    setInterval(mainLoop, refreshTime);
    //}

    // main loop now handles timing as well
    function mainLoop() {
        if(backGroundChange){  // change the background here if needed
            ctx.fillStyle = "#000000";
            ctx.fillRect(0, 0, width, height);
            backGroundChange = false;
        }

        // instead of y = y + blockSpacingY
        // use short hand y += blockSpacingY it is the same as above
        for (y = 0; y < height; y += blockSpacingY) { 
            for (x = 0; x < width; x += blockSpacingX) {
                ctx.fillStyle = '#' + Math.floor(Math.random() * 16777215).toString(16);
                ctx.fillRect(x, y, blockWidth, blockHeight);
            }
        }
        // schedual the next render
        setTimeout(mainLoop,refreshTime)
    }

    mainLoop(); // this starts rendering and will continue
```

Hope this helps and that I have not missed anything.

Comment: Thanks this helped a ton, and thanks for looking at and cleaning up the rest of it too :D